# WPF TabControl changing SelectedIndex / SelectedItem causes binding errors

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, tabcontrol

I have been trying to solve this problem for about a week now, unable to find anything helpful to solve this.
I am rather inexperienced in the Data Binding approach WPF takes (in comparison to Unity, WinForms etc.) and was hoping someone here might be able to help out.

I am working on a WPF application in C# to be able to display *.csv files in a DataGrid and compare one with the other (so I would likely need 3 TabControls: 2 of them to load in a *.csv and a final one to display results in 3 tabs (matches, differences A -> B and differences (B -> A)).

The problem I am struggling with is manipulating the TabControl without errors.
Whenever I close a tab after I set the tab to the last tab, I get hit with a very unhelpful error message:
Error; 4; null; TabStripPlacement; TabItem.NoTarget; Object; Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl', AncestorLevel='1'.

What I did notice is if I am not setting the SelectedIndex, and remove a tab, all is good (though not what I want).

The error can be consistantly recreated by drag and dropping a *.csv file into the tabControl, then closing it with the 'x'.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CsvComparer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CsvComparer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:TabViewModel xmlns="clr-namespace:CsvComparer"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                x:Name="firstFileTabControl"         
                ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                TabStripPlacement="Top"
                AllowDrop="True"
                Drop="FileTabControl_OnDrop"                    
                Tag="0">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Button Content="X" Click="TabCloseButton_Click" Tag="{Binding InstanceId}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}" 
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                          CanUserResizeRows="False"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The Models:

```
public sealed class TabItemModel
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public DataTable DataTable { get; set; }        
    public long InstanceId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TabViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<TabItemModel> Tabs { get; set; }

    private int selectedIndex = 0;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedIndex;
        }

        set
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedIndex)));
            selectedIndex = value;
        }
    }

    public TabViewModel()
    {
        Tabs = new();
    }
}
```

The C# Code in the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CsvComparer
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new TabViewModel();
    }

    #region EventHandlers

    private long instanceCount = 0;
    private void FileTabControl_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] fileNames = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            string file = fileNames.FirstOrDefault();

            TabItemModel newTab = new()
            {
                InstanceId = instanceCount++,
                Header = $"{ System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) }",
                DataTable = GetCsvRecords(file),                    
            };

            var model = (TabViewModel)DataContext;
            model.Tabs.Add(newTab);
            
            // when commenting out this line, no errors
            model.SelectedIndex++;                                
        }
    }

    private void TabCloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        long id = (long)button.Tag;

        var model = (TabViewModel)DataContext;
        var item = model.Tabs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InstanceId == id);
        if (item != null)
        {
            model.Tabs.Remove(item);
        }            
    }

    #endregion

    private CsvConfiguration CreateCsvConfig()
    {
        CsvConfiguration output = new CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            // Delimiter = ", ",
            BadDataFound = new BadDataFound((data) => Debug.WriteLine($"Found faulty data: '{ data.RawRecord }'")),
            MissingFieldFound = new MissingFieldFound((data) => Debug.WriteLine($"Missing field found at Row '{ data.Index }', Header '{ data.HeaderNames }'")),
            ShouldSkipRecord = record => record.Record.All(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace),
        };

        return output;
    }

    private DataTable GetCsvRecords(string path, CsvConfiguration config = null)
    {
        DataTable output = new();
        config ??= CreateCsvConfig();

        using (StreamReader sr = new(path))
        {
            using (CsvReader csvReader = new(sr, config))
            {
                using (CsvDataReader dataReader = new(csvReader))
                {
                    output.Load(dataReader);
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my hunch as to what is happening: say you have three tabs open and you have the final tab selected (SelectedIndex=2). After closing a tab, the observable collection will only contain two tab items, so you get the binding error because the value of SelectedIndex (2) is now invalid.

The fix may be as simple as updating the value of the SelectedIndex property from within TabCloseButton_Click, but do so right before you remove the tab item. This won't be necessary if the value of SelectedIndex is less than the index of the tab being removed (as SelectedIndex will remain valid after removal).

Comment: Just tried it out and sadly that still causes the error to happen...
I have a feeling that maybe the tabcontrol still holds on to the, now removed, tabitem...